# Instance of an abstract class not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, class, abstract-class

I'm sure many of you would mark this as repeaed the second you see the title. Please bear with me..Facing a complicated issue. :)

Thanks for reading till here :D

So, I have a class called InfoClass, which is abstract-

```
public abstract class InfoClass
{
    public abstract string Brand { get; set; }
    public abstract string BrandCount { get; set; }
}
```

I have a service in which I'm making a list out of it..and down the line tryin to make an instance of the same. But not able to-

```
[WebMethod]
    public void GetInfoList()
    {
        List<InfoClass> listInformations = new List<InfoClass>();
        .
        .
        .      //Going ahead in the program I've created a reader
        .
        .
        .
        .
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                //This is the block not working
                InfoClass Advertises = new InfoClass();
                Advertises.Brand = Convert.ToString(rdr["Brand"]);                    
            }
```

Please help me out with an alternative to the code. I'm sure the class is meant to be abstract, So we cant change it on the class level.

Comment: It's not possible to create an instance of an abstract class. That's the whole point. If you have an abstract class, you need another class that inherits from it and provides implementations for the abstract members of the abstract class. In your example there seems to be no reason for it to be an abstract class. At most it could be an interface, at which point you'd still have to create a class that implements that interface.

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm used more to Java, but things seem to be similar for c#.

Abstract classes can't be instanciated as you can see in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf(v=vs.71).aspx)

> They are classes that cannot be instantiated, and are frequently
>   either partially implemented, or not at all implemented.

thus `new InfoClass();` is not valid.
You have to either make `InfoClass` not abstract, or create another class that inherits `InfoClass` and instanciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit the abstract type with another type, and implement the abstract method(s), if any

```
public class ConcreteInfoClass : InfoClass {}
```

Use it now this way

```
InfoClass Advertises = new ConcreteInfoClass();
Advertises.Brand = Convert.ToString(rdr["Brand"]);
```

Comment: Lemme try that...looks promising (y)